# Running two queries on the same table and implement them on the same route

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

How can I make this work?

I think I should use promises but I don't have much knowledge about  them. I've read about them but couldn't create the structure as it's supposed to.

I simply wanna run two different queries on the same table and use the returning values on the same ejs file

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    db.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, FORMAT(SUM(donation_amount),2) AS total FROM donations;', (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        let count = result[0].count; //since query column is requested as "count". we can use "count" to get back the raw value
        let total = result[0].total;
        res.render('home', { count: count, total: total }); // just the file name is enough. ejs engine looks up the file name in the "views" folder
    });

    db.query('SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ", ", last_name AS latest_donator, donation_amount AS amount FROM donations ORDER BY donation_time LIMIT 1;', (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        let donatorName = result[0].latest_donator;
        let amount = result[0].amount;
        res.render('home', {first_name: donatorName, amount: amount});
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only send the response (`res.render(...)`) once you have the result of both queries. Therefore you may want to do them sequentially like this.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, FORMAT(SUM(donation_amount),2) AS total FROM donations;', (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        let count = result[0].count; //since query column is requested as "count". we can use "count" to get back the raw value
        let total = result[0].total;
        db.query('SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ", ", last_name AS latest_donator, donation_amount AS amount FROM donations ORDER BY donation_time LIMIT 1;', (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            let donatorName = result[0].latest_donator;
            let amount = result[0].amount;
            res.render('home', { first_name: donatorName, amount: amount, count: count, total: total });
        });
    });
});
```

But the queries are independent from eachother so you could run them in parallel.

Comment: Thanks man. That was a good answer. Also could you point me out a beginner friendly introduction docs/tutorials etc. for promises if it's not too much to ask?

Comment: Checkout the Mdn documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)